# Where condition along with group_by oprion in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails so please anybody tell me how to use group_by option in controller page and and along with group_by i want to count the name through the Where Condition

Comment: table name cities i want to group_by particular city name and count how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
City.group_by(&:name)
```

The above statement will give you array of hash, in which key will be city_name and values will be array of city records.

Then if you need only count of each of array of city records for all the cities then you can do it by creating a new variable and storing the count of records along with their name using :

```
city_count = {}
City.group_by(&:name).each do |city_name, city_records|
    city_count[city_name] = city_records.count
end
```

The above code will return you the array of hash which has key as city_name and the number of records as value.

Answer (score 2):

In City Model add a scope.

`scope :by_name, lambda { |name| where(name: name) }`

When you call count on the scope

`City.by_name('London').count`

The following MySql will be executed...

`SELECT count(*) FROM`cities`WHERE`cities`.`name`= 'London'`

Comment: City.group_by(&:name).count this one i asked and i have one doubt charles what is use of this (&:)

Comment: `(&:name)` is the same as calling `each { |x| x.name  }`